# Camera2Video Api full screen preview and video quality

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm building an app regarding camera2video API. Wanted to show the preview full screen, but instead it is occupying 70% area of the screen as shown in the Camera2video API Github https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video
And also there is no option for Video Quality parameter as it was available in the deprecated Camera API.

Answer (score 1):

The `Camera2Video` demo contains a class called `AutoFitTextureView` that fits the preview inside a texture view while preserving the aspect ratio. If you want to stretch the preview to fill the whole screen, just use a regular `TextureView` instead of this class.

You'll need to replace the references to `AutoFitTextureView` in the `Camera2VideoFragment` class, and also in the layout XML files for both portrait and landscape. Change the `layout_width` and `layout_height` to `match_parent`.

> And also there is no option for Video Quality parameter as it was available in the deprecated Camera API

Set it on the [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) object (`mMediaRecorder`) in `Camera2VideoFragment`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, regarding the full screen preview I have tried replacing AutoFitTextureView with TextureView, but the preview is stretched from top to bottom and is not looking good. :(

Comment: Is the problem that the orientation of the preview doesn't match the orientation of the screen?

Comment: The orientation matches, for instance I'm viewing in portrait mode, then the camera preview is also in portrait mode but the preview is stretched.

Comment: Ok, so what do you want to do? If the preview only takes 70% of the screen when not stretched, it's going to be stretched if you make it full screen, it's unavoidable. The only way for it not to appear stretched would be if you chop off part of the preview. Also, make sure you are using the preview resolution that matches the aspect ratio of your screen as closely as possible (in the `chooseOptimalSize` function).

Comment: Hmm.. Chop off the preview would be a great, can you just guide me to chop off the preview.

Comment: You'll need to set a transform on the TextureView. It's done in the `configureTransform` function in `Camera2VideoFragment`.

Comment: I have been stuck in the video quality issue. 
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        profile.videoFrameWidth = mPreviewSize.getWidth();
        profile.videoFrameHeight = mPreviewSize.getHeight();
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
I have implemented the above code in setupMediaRecorder () method in Camera2VideoFragment. But the app is crashing

Comment: Sorry, to set the video quality I have to use the camcorderprofile as used in the older CameraApi

Comment: So what do I need to do for video quality. It will be very helpful from your side if code for the same be provided.Thanks

Comment: Call CamcorderProfile.get, then call mMediaRecorder.setProfile. You can't set the fields of the profile, you can only choose which profile to use. You can call hasProfile to check if a profile is supported.

Comment: CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        mMediaRecorder.setProfile(profile);
It has still not resolved the issue. Actually, setupmediarecorder () is being called when the recording function defined in Camera2VideoFragment is executed, which is crashing the app with an IllegalStateException

Comment: Try getting the profile, then calling the functions that are called in setupmediarecorder, but passing the values read out of the profile, instead of setting the profile. e.g. `mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);` etc. I don't know why it isn't working the other way though.

Comment: Hey guys.. any final solution for the full screen preview? i really stuck. please help.

Answer (score 1):

The camera2 implement not so good. In your case, you find the method **chooseVideoSize** and change by following:

```
private Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {

        for (Size size : choices) {
            if (size.getWidth() == size.getHeight() * 16 / 9 && size.getWidth() <= 1080) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }
```

Next, you should insert **android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"** into fragment_camera2_video.xml of default layout folder. It looks like:

```
<com.example.android.camera2video.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" //add here
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
        }
    }
```

Change this in AutoFitTextureview class of onMeasure method

Comment: Do you still remember what this does? I mean does it stretch it and cut the edges? At least for me, the camera preview now fits the whole screen but it looks like its leaving something out. The width seems to be OK now, but the height is really wrong.

Comment: @kataroty did you fix the height issue

Comment: @FrankOdoom yep, I do not remember how I did it though.

Comment: @kataroty can you please find out i need some insight into this, will much appreciate it